# How to get return value of c++ int main() output using subprocess.check_output() in python script

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, return-value, cout

I am using a C++ script as follows:

```cpp
int main(){
 int x =7;
 std::cout<<"print num:"<<x<<std::endl;
 if(x>0){
  std::cout<<" good"<<std::endl;
  return 5;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

For this in my python file I am calling the subprocess as follows:

```python
result0_1 = subprocess.check_output(MYCPP_fILE_PATH,shell =True)
print(result0_1.decode("utf-8"))
```

It prints out "print num:" and "good" but dosn't provide me the return value "5".

How can I get the return value but not the std::cout from the cpp file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

And very similar [Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a `CalledProcessError`. The
> `CalledProcessError` object will have **the return code** in the `returncode`
> attribute and any `output` in the output attribute.